# Zip function for unzipping elements

Tags: python, list

Why am I obtaining the following result:

```
[('a', 'b', 'o'), ('p', 'a', 'r'), ('p', 'n', 'a'), ('l', 'a', 'n'), ('e', 'n', 'g')]
```

instead of:

```
[('a','p','p','l','e'), ('b','a','n','a','n','a'), ....]
```

from the following script:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]
var = zip(*fruits)
print(list(var))
```

I am expecting a different result from this script.

Answer (score 1):

According to documenation at https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip
"Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables"

In your case each string in fruits list is interpreted as list of chars. Zip returns list of tuple consisting of chars from each string at i-th position

Comment: This doesn't answer the Op's need, it only comments on why the Op's code doesn't work as desired.

Comment: @MatBailie Why do you say that? An explanation for the OP's code's behavior is exactly what the question asks for.

Comment: @MatBailie It answers the posted question "Why am I obtaining the following result". It is not explicitly clear if "need" is alternative code or understanding. In terms of code, I see that other answers already added it. I believe, my answer provides the understanding part.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list of tuples where each tuple contains the characters of a single string, you can use a list comprehension.

Here's the corrected script:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]
var = [tuple(s) for s in fruits]
print(var)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'), ('b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a'), ('o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e')]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another alternative solution using a combination of list comprehension and the `*` operator:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]
var = [(*s,) for s in fruits]
print(var)
```

The output remains the same:

```
[('a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'), ('b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a'), ('o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e')]
```

Answer (score -1):

To get that result you need to convert the strings into tuples (no need for zip):

```
*var, = map(tuple,fruits)

[('a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'), ('b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a'), 
 ('o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e')]
```